# Class 'ZipArchive' not found. how to configure zip on php apache

Tags: centos7, php.ini, php7

Following is the error message that i am receiving [image] 
I searched through internet and did installed zip using

```
sudo yum install php70-php-pecl-zip
```

when i do `yum list installed`, it shows me that "`zip.x86_64`" is there but when i do phpinfo() it doesn't shows me zip extension installed.

It looks like it is not loading the `zip.ini` in `/etc/php.d/` directory

any help will be appreciate thanks. i am running `centos 7`
 and `php 7.0.27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual package name on centos 7 is `php-pecl-zip.x86_64`.

Try installing that and enabling it by running:

```
echo "extension=zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

Comment: What is installation command..?

Comment: It's in the OPs post, read it carefully.